# DataTable row returns undefined

Tags: asp.net-core, datatables, jquery-plugins

I have a JQuery DataTable. Fpr each row I have a button and when the user clicks on it, it should show related fields in a modal in order to edit that row. Now my problem is I can't get the selected row id and it returns undefined. Here is my code:

```
  $("#myDummyTable").DataTable({

            "processing": true, // for show progress bar
            "serverSide": true, // for process server side
            "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
            "orderMulti": false,
            //"searching": false,
            "language": {
                "url": "/language/Persian.json"
            },
            "ajax": {
                "url": "Data/GetData",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "jason"
            },
            "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": [0],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            }],

            rowId: "id",
        

             "columns": [
                { "data": "id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true },

                 { "data": "startDate", "name": "StartDate", "autoWidth": true },
                 { "data": "endDate", "name": "EndDate", "autoWidth": true },
                {
                defaultContent: '<input type="button" class="Edit" value="edit"/>
                }

            ]

        });

            $('#myDummyTable tbody').on('click', '.Edit', function () {
                var row = myDummyTable.row(this).rowId;
                var myDummyTable = $('#myDummyTable').DataTable();
                console.log('row:' + myDummyTable.row(this).rowId);
         
                

      
});

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `defaultContent` column option, you can use a `render` function. This allows you to customize each button so it can include the relevant ID:

```
{ data: "id", render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
        return '<input type="button" class="Edit" id="' + data + '" value="edit id ' + data + '"/>';
  }
}
```

Here we first use `data: id` again (same as for the first column). This means this column will use the `id` value.

Then we use the `render` function which gives us access to the id value via the `data` variable.

In my example I added the ID to the text used by each button.

I also added an id attribute to each of these cells, using the same `data` value. This assumes each ID is unique, of course.

My test data - an example of one row:

```
{
  "id": "5",
  "name": "Airi Satou",
  "start_date": "2008/11/28",
  "office": "Tokyo"
}
```

In this case, Airi Satou's ID is `5`.

My test table:

[image]

Now, when I click on a button, the following code will print the related ID:

```
$('#myDummyTable tbody').on('click', '.Edit', function () {
  console.log( this.id );
});
```